# Why "POST /rest/V1/order/:orderID/ship" doesn't work in Magento 2.1.1 CE?

Tags: magento2, shipment

Why does "POST /rest/V1/order/{orderId}/ship" not work in Magento 2.1.1 CE?

Returns error : "Request does not match any route error" in Ship Method.

Answer (score 2):

what are you searching exactly?

the webapi.xml declares the service layer interface and method here

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/webapi.xml#L251

the interface is defined here:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/Api/ShipOrderInterface.php#L28

for the interface, the class preference is declared here:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/di.xml#L73

and the class implements the service method here:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ShipOrder.php#L139

so, posting to the url `/V1/order/:orderId/ship` should invoke the ececute method int the `Magento\Sales\Model\ShipOrder` Class

Comment: Thanks for reply ! 

It has now become clearer how !!!

Comment: Thanks and forgive me , but version is 2.1.1 not 2.1.3, i'm wrong in question.